# Matlab: displaying message and cell array in msgbox

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array 'Animals' with contents as:

```
'Cat'
'Dogs'
'Elephant'
```

I want to display in a messagebox the following:

```
The only animals in our zoo are:
Cat
Dogs
Elephant
```

How do I achieve this?

Edit:
Sorry for the confusion: the contents of the cell array 'Animals' will change every time user runs the code. The size of 'Animals' is mostly 3x1 or 4x1. So, the variable size and contents has to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy if you read the [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/msgbox.html) for `msgbox`:

```
intro = 'The only animals in our zoo are:'
animals = {'Cat','Dogs','Elephant'}; % Define as desired:
msgbox([intro animals])
```

Comment: Sorry the array has variable content and size. But it is of size 3x1 or 4x1 mostly.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use a cell array `animals` which contains the data